# Google Maps API v3 Remove "Click to see this area on Google Maps" link

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I know that it is against the Google Maps API ToS to remove the Google branding or the ToS link that are overlaid across the bottom of the map, but I'm using the maps API to display a video game map, and the Google logo links to the main Google Maps site in such a way that it sends you to a real-world map at the same world coordinates as the current view of my in-game map, which completely doesn't make sense for this use case.  Is there any way to disable the link to Google Maps from clicking on the Google logo?  I've seen CSS examples for removing the logo, but the link remains.  I don't even care about having the logo, and for the sake of the ToS, I'd prefer to leave it there, but is there any way to disable the link?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms of service for a 3rd party application.  Legal advice should not be recommended by anyone.

Comment: I'm not looking for legal advice as to the legitimacy of what I wish to do, I am only looking for technical advice as to how to achieve it.  I'll deal with the legal ramifications, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use JavaScript to make the link do nothing after the map has loaded:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    l = anchors.length,
    i,
    a;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    a = anchors[i];
    if (a.href.indexOf('maps.google.com/maps?') !== -1) {
         a.title = ''; 
         a.onclick = function () { return false; };
    }
}
```

You'd probably have to redo this when the map is changed (cache the anchor tag so you don't have to search for it each time).

Comment: Awesome, that worked great.  Is there any way to remove the actual content of the link so that the intended target url doesn't show up in the bottom-left of the browser (obviously, this differs by browser, but most browsers display the target url when you hover over a link).  This does disable the link so you can't click on it, as well as removes the hover-text, so functionally, this does what I need, it would just be nice to remove the link target as well, if possible.

Comment: @qwertymodo just set the href to nothing - although, as it's still a hyperlink you'd just get the current url showing up when you hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the map's 'idle' event and then use jQuery to remove the link like this:

```
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function (e) {
    $('a[title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"]').remove();
});
```

This would break, of course, if they ever changed the text that is defined for the `title` attribute so maybe someone else can suggest a better selector -- one that would look at a portion of the `href` for example.

Whether or not something like this would violate the terms of usage I cannot comment on.