# How to add marker to google logo destination?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a map object with a long/lat position as center. When clicking the google logo in the bottom left corner you are routed to google maps with the same position as center. But in the embedded map I have also added a marker at the center position.

Is it possible to have that marker set when you route to google maps as well?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo's link looks like this:

`https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.758893,-73.985132&z=10&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3`

In your case all you have to do is change the parameters of the link. 
Using the `?q=40.758893,-73.985132` parameter instead of `?ll=40.758893,-73.985132` is probably enough for you. The `q=latitude,longitude` puts a marker to the position. Although it is possible to use both parameters. The `q` is the marker's position and the `ll` is the center of the map. (use the `&` separator between them).
I think it is against the Google Maps API ToS to modify the Google branding or the link. But anyway it is possible with javascript. 
You can see the original answer here: [How to change Google logo's href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281913/how-to-change-google-logos-href?lq=1)

After the map is loaded you can manipulate the link:

```
...
map.addListener('tilesloaded', function(){
    modifyLogoLink();
});
...
```

And here is how to change the link:

```
function modifyLogoLink(){
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        l = anchors.length,
        i,
        a;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        a = anchors[i];
        if (a.href.indexOf('maps.google.com/maps?') !== -1) {
             // here you can manipulate the anchor
             a.href =  a.href.replace('ll=', 'q=')
        }
    }       
}
```

Please also note that the Google's link is changed every time when the map is dragged or zoomed. So you must handle this as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All right thanks! But I think I'll pass if it violates the terms!

Comment: Well I am not sure if modifying this link violates the ToS, but if you want to be sure, here are the links: [https://developers.google.com/maps/terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) , [https://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html)